# Sorting a list of directories that contain numbers with a different number of digits

Tags: shell-script, sorting, ksh, csh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In bash, how to sort strings with numbers in them?](https://superuser.com/questions/79338/in-bash-how-to-sort-strings-with-numbers-in-them)

We have the following directory structure on our file-system:

```
ver30
ver20
ver50
ver70
ver100
ver90
```

I want to create a short script that prints the list in sorted order, i.e:

```
ver20
ver30
ver50
ver70
ver90
ver100
```

However, the command I have: `ls -d ver*e | tr '  ' '\n' | sort` produces this:

```
ver100
ver20
ver30
ver50
ver70
ver90
```

Any easy way to do it? If not, any hard way to do it?

I prefer a CSH answer, but KSH is also fine. (AWK is fine, but I promise to copy it without asking why it works)

Comment: (from dupe): sort -n -k2 -tr  (sort numerically, on second field, split fields on the letter "r"

Comment: @Sirex Well, that one's about `bash`, not `csh` or `ksh`, as requested by OP. But if it works, I guess it can be closed.

Comment: Many thanks - `sort -n -k2 -tr` does solve the problem quite easily.
I'll close the question

Granted - the "winning" answer on that post does not solve my problem.